# Why are some products imported from CSV missing their default Name, Descriptions, and Prices?

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0, ce-1.9.2.1

In Magento CE ver. 1.9.1.0 and 1.9.2.1 we have run into an issue where imported products are missing certain default fields, even though those fields are present and correct in the source CSV.  The fields that are missing are the default Name, Description, Short Description, and Price.  We're using the basic import function in Magento.

We have a multi-store setup with 7 stores and are using some custom product attributes (26 of them).

If a product has a different description for one of the stores, the field for that Store View is populated but greyed out, with the "use default values" checkbox checked.

We have increased the memory to PHP as well as processing time, we've created a new CSV from scratch and imported dummy data.

There is a pattern to the missing data, as well. It seems to start with the 15th product, and then repeats every 15 or so products afterwards.  All the products in between seem fine.

The CSV validates with no errors.  If we import or re-import the products with errors by themselves without otherwise changing the data in the CSV, they import fine with no errors, unless we import more than 15 at once.

We have tried installing the newest version of magento on our server, and have even tried testing a standalone XAMPP installation.  The same errors seem to occur on every install we try, which leads us to believe that there's either a configuration error on our part, or a fundamental issue in Magento.

Searching the internet has not revealed many people with the same issue as we're facing, so we're at a loss. As far as we can see, the stores are all set up properly, and the product attributes are just basic stuff created via the Magento backend.

What could be causing such regular errors?

Comment: I think you would have to dump out the data durnin the processing to find out why every 15th product fails.

Comment: How can we do that?

Comment: you would have to create a module that extends the /app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport functionality to give you the output in various stages so you can see where it's going wrong. Or write your own import script rather than using the Magento functionality.

Comment: Just to be clear, the products missing the required info do not have any foreign chars in them, do they? On anther note, maybe you could use http://magmi.org/

Comment: The products don't have foreign characters.  If we extract the rows from the CSV that contain the problem products and import them separately, they import fine with no errors.  We've looked at Magmi and unfortunately that won't solve our particular problem in the long term because a 3rd party service we're using to provide product updates from our main inventory software uses the CSV import functionality of Magento.

Comment: After adding logging, we determined that the errors were occuring with product rows that started new "chunks" of data that the Magento import code was creating as it loaded the CSV into the DB.  We have not managed to find and fix the code issues, as such, but we have apparently stopped triggering the issue by increasing the bunch_size in ImportExport/etc/config.xml to a large enough number that all of the data we need to update is in a single chunk/bunch/segment/whatever.  We imported 1400 products without any errors so it seems to be a workaround.  The underlying issue still remains unsolved

Comment: I'm glad you managed to find a workaround through log outputs at various stages. Maybe you can edit your original question with all the info you have on the issue so far, possibly changing the title, so maybe someone else can have a look at it and see if it's a magento bug or else.